# Exception thrown by composite component action method is completely swallowed

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, mojarra

I'm using Mojarra 2.1.13 with Spring on a portal. I've a command button in a composite component whose action is defined in client. When an exception occurs in the action method, then this exception is completely swallowed and a different exception is being thrown, which made debugging difficult.

I created an SSCCE. This is the composite, `simpleBtn.xhtml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="action" targets="button" required="true" />
        <composite:attribute name="label" />
        <composite:attribute name="update" />
        <composite:attribute name="execute" targets="button" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <h:commandButton id="button" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
            <f:ajax render="#{cc.attrs.update}" execute="#{cc.attrs.execute}" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </composite:implementation>

</html>
```

This is the Spring managed bean, `com.example.Bean`:

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class Bean {

    public void execute() {
        Object o = new Integer(2);
        System.out.println((String) o); // Class cast exception thrown here
    }

}
```

This is the view, `page.xhtml`:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <button:simpleBtn label="button" action="#{bean.execute}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

When pressing the button, you'd expect to see `ClassCastException` in the log. However, this is not happening. Instead, the following are actually being logged:

```
...
Caused by: javax.portlet.faces.BridgeException: javax.faces.FacesException: can't parse argument number: bean.execute
...
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: can't parse argument number: bean.execute
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: bean.execute
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "bean.execute"
...
```

I debugged and I noticed that the `ClassCastException` is being caught in `catch (ELException ele) {...}` block of `ContextualCompositeMethodExpression#invoke(ELContext, Object[])` method, but the `ele` is in turn never thrown because of newly raised exceptions thrown in `catch (Exception ex)` a few lines later.

How is this caused and how can I get the `ClassCastException` to show up in the log anyway?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I am trying to ask something like that: "Why I am not getting class cast exception in my log even if it thrown in my bean's method.".

Comment: Okay. I recall this ever being reported as bug to JSF guys, but I can't find the issue report in question right now. Mojarra 2.1.13 is relatively old (this week exactly 1 year old). Have you tried the latest, 2.1.26?

Comment: I just tried 2.1.26 but in my log there is no mention about exception (`java.lang.ClassCastException`) thrown in my bean's method because it is never thrown after it is caught by `com.sun.el.parser.AstValue#invoke`.

Comment: I found the report I had in mind: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1806. But it's after all somewhat different. I tried to reproduce your problem using 2.1.26, but I can't. It just throws the `ClassCastException`. Have you tried to reproduce your problem using standard JSF without Liferay/Spring? Perhaps one of them is causing this problem. I don't do Spring, but I know that it comes with an EL resolver. Perhaps it did its job wrong?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question to make it look a bit less ranty and make the concrete problem clear in the title.